# How to write an Ansible playbook with port knocking

Tags: ansible, port

My server is set up to require port knocking in order to white-list an IP for port 22 SSH. I've found guides on setting up an Ansible playbook to configure port knocking on the server side, but not to perform port knocking on the client side.

For example, what would my playbook and/or inventory files look like if I need to knock port 9999, 9000, then connect to port 22 in order to run my Ansible tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try out my [ssh_pkn](https://github.com/berlic/ansibledaily/blob/master/connection_plugins/ssh_pkn.py) connection plugin.

```
# Example host definition:
#   [pkn]
#   myserver ansible_host=my.server.at.example.com
#   [pkn:vars]
#   ansible_connection=ssh_pkn
#   knock_ports=[8000,9000]
#   knock_delay=2
```

Comment: Thanks for the plugin - it's working great! I did notice that Ansible seems to reconnect SSH (and port knock with this plugin) for EVERY single task. Does that sound correct?

In this case, the plugin slows down playbook execution quite a bit, when I really only need port-knocking at the beginning of the playbook. Once knocked, the client IP is whitelisted for X minutes.

Would it be possible to have the plugin first try port 22 like usual, then after X timeout, port knock instead? Or, is there another simpler way to achieve this that I'm not considering?

Comment: If connection is indeed closed, it will init from scratch with port-knocking; but If it is reusable (like control-master), port-knocking will not be made with every task (only with first one).

Answer (score 2):

I have used https://stackoverflow.com/a/42647902/10191134 until it broke on an ansible update so I searched for another solution and finally stumbled over [wait_for](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html):

hosts:

```
[myserver]
knock_ports=[123,333,444]
```

play:

```
- name: Port knocking
  wait_for:
    port: "{{ item }}"
    delay: 0
    connect_timeout: 1
    state: stopped
    host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
  connection: local
  become: no
  with_items: "{{ knock_ports }}"
  when: knock_ports is defined
```

ofc can be adjusted to make the delay and/or timeout configurable in the hosts as well.

Comment: Works very well. This is brilliant :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a brute-force example. The timeouts will be hit, so this'll add 2 seconds per host to a play.

```
- hosts: all
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - uri:
      url: "http://{{ansible_host}}:9999"
      timeout: 1
    ignore_errors: yes
  - uri:
      url: "http://{{ansible_host}}:9000"
      timeout: 1
    ignore_errors: yes
  - hosts: all
  # your normal plays here
```

Other ways: use `telnet`, [put a wrapper around Ansible](https://lionfacelemonface.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/centralized-ansible-management-with-knockd-auto-provisioning-with-aws/) (though it [isn't recommended in Ansible2](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/dev_guide/developing_api.html)), make a role and then include with `meta`, write a custom module (and pull that back into Ansible itself).

Comment: Great idea! This worked for me after replacing ansible_host with inventory_hostname